# Why is PHP Mailer undefined, while I used the same name as in the documention

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I want to send emails with the help of PHPMailer. The goal is to use PHPMailer, connect with their host and get messages. But I get the error code: `Undefined type 'PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer'`
Already used all kinds of tricks to get it working, but I can't seem to figure it out. Here is m code for reference.

```
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
require '/vendor/autoload.php';

$errors = [];
$errorMessage = '';

if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    if (empty($name)) {
        $errors[] = 'Name is empty';
    }

    if (empty($email)) {
        $errors[] = 'Email is empty';
    } else if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $errors[] = 'Email is invalid';
    }

    if (empty($message)) {
        $errors[] = 'Message is empty';
    }


    if (!empty($errors)) {
        $allErrors = join('<br/>', $errors);
        $errorMessage = "<p style='color: red;'>{$allErrors}</p>";
    } else {
        
        $phpmailer = new PHPMailer(true);
        $phpmailer->isSMTP();
        $phpmailer->Host = 'smtp.mailtrap.io';
        $phpmailer->SMTPAuth = true;
        $phpmailer->Port = 2525;
        $phpmailer->Username = '***';
        $phpmailer->Password = '***';

        $mail->setFrom($email, 'Mailtrap Website');
        $mail->addAddress('test@mailtrap.io', 'Me');
        $mail->Subject = 'New message from your website';

        // Enable HTML if needed
        $mail->isHTML(true);

        $bodyParagraphs = ["Name: {$name}", "Email: {$email}", "Message:", nl2br($message)];
        $body = join('<br />', $bodyParagraphs);
        $mail->Body = $body;

        echo $body;
        if($mail->send()){

            header('Location: thank-you.html'); // redirect to 'thank you' page
        } else {
            $errorMessage = 'Oops, something went wrong. Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        }
    }
}

?>

<html>
<body>
  <form action="/swiftmailer_form.php" method="post" id="contact-form">
    <h2>Contact us</h2>

    <?php echo((!empty($errorMessage)) ? $errorMessage : '') ?>
    <p>
      <label>First Name:</label>
      <input name="name" type="text" value="dima"/>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label>Email Address:</label>
      <input style="cursor: pointer;" name="email" value="dima@dima.com" type="text"/>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label>Message:</label>
      <textarea name="message">dima</textarea>
    </p>

    <p>
      <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
    </p>
  </form>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/validate.js/0.13.1/validate.min.js"></script>
  <script>
      const constraints = {
          name: {
              presence: {allowEmpty: false}
          },
          email: {
              presence: {allowEmpty: false},
              email: true
          },
          message: {
              presence: {allowEmpty: false}
          }
      };

      const form = document.getElementById('contact-form');

      form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
          const formValues = {
              name: form.elements.name.value,
              email: form.elements.email.value,
              message: form.elements.message.value
          };

          const errors = validate(formValues, constraints);

          if (errors) {
              event.preventDefault();
              const errorMessage = Object
                  .values(errors)
                  .map(function (fieldValues) {
                      return fieldValues.join(', ')
                  })
                  .join("\n");

              alert(errorMessage);
          }
      }, false);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What version of PHPMailer are you using? What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: Your `require` statement is looking at the root of the system which is probably not what you want.

Comment: you are using the class before it get autoload so just  require '/vendor/autoload.php';  must be the very first line in the code

Comment: @BlackXero – `use` statements are local aliases that do not need to have corresponding classes loaded, and they are conventionally placed first in the file, before autoload.

Comment: @Quentin PHPMailer = 6.6,  PHP = 8.1.6

Comment: @ChrisHaas Do what can I change it to, already tried `__dir__`.

Comment: It depends on your folder structure. If the file and vendor folder are siblings, you can call `require_once __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php`. If the file is in a sub-folder, you’ll need to add some `../` into the mix

Comment: Invalid paths trigger clear error messages, which you don't seem to be seeing. Please check at least the TL;DR section at [PHP error reporting](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting).

Comment: Check the path to your vendor folder: "/vendor/autoload.php" might be "vendor/autoload.php" here